# How to extract text which is surrounded by two <span> element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am in mid of scraping data from a website, but I encounter following code

```
code = "<li class="price-current">
<span class="price-current-label">
</span>₹ 7,372 
            <span class="price-current-range">
<abbr title="to">–</abbr>
</span>
</li> "
```

I need to extract only "₹ 7,372".

I have tried following.
1. `Code.text`
but it result to

```
'\n\n₹ 7,372\xa0\r\n            \n–\n\n'
```

2. `code.text.strip()`
   but it result to

   '₹ 7,372\xa0\r\n            \n–'

Is there any method?
Please let me know, so that I can complete my project.

Comment: You can try code.text.strip().split('\xa0')[0].

Comment: it results to 

'₹ 7,372 \n            \n–'

I have tried it already, that's why I have asked here

Comment: I don't think it will give output as you mentioned if the string is `code.text` mentioned in your question.
`print "\n\n₹ 7,372\xa0\r\n            \n–\n\n".strip().split('\xa0')[0]` == > ₹ 7,372

Comment: yes, it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to clean data that you need. This way is a little ugly, but works=)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html= """<li class="price-current">
<span class="price-current-label">
</span>₹ 7,372 
            <span class="price-current-range">
<abbr title="to">–</abbr>
</span>
</li> """

soup=BS(html)

li = soup.find('li').text

for j in range(3):
    for i in ['\n',' ', '–', '\xa0', '\r','\x20','\x0a','\x09','\x0c','\x0d']:
        li=li.strip(i)

print(li)
```

output:

```
₹ 7,372
```

In the loop list I outlined all (as far as I know) ASCII spaces and the symbols that you get.

Loop launches 3 times because needed value doesn't clean from the first time, you can check it every iteration in variable explorer.

Also optionally you can try to figure out what precise symbol gives a lot of pseudo `spaces` between `<span>` tags.

Comment: Hey @Dmitriy Fialkovskiy !
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
code = '''<li class="price-current">
<span class="price-current-label">
</span>₹ 7,372 
            <span class="price-current-range">
<abbr title="to">–</abbr>
</span>
</li>'''
soup = bs(code,'html.parser')
w = soup.find_all('li')
l = []
for item in w:
    l.append(item)
words = str(l)
t = words.split('\n')
print(t[2][7:])
₹ 7,372
```